# Get data modifier "Subsurf" after rayСast

Tags: python

I use rayCast to get index of a polygon under the cursor. After that i check the object for modifiers, if there are modifiers I use this:

`obj.to_mesh(context.scene, apply_modifiers=True, settings='PREVIEW')`

So I can get edges and vertices of that polygon. But this code doesn't work with Subsurf modifier.

.to_mesh()

Indexes mess. How can I solve this problem? I don't want to use Bmesh, because it takes a lot of time to create bm on heavy meshes.

[image]

Comment: `mesh = obj.to_mesh(...)` makes a new mesh from the  object with the modifiers applied.  Kinda like applying all modifiers, but not on `obj.data` on a copy.   Are you linking it to object `obj.data = mesh` before running  your raycast.... but the subsurf modified mesh copy will have a lot more faces than the original ...   Without code it's a bit difficult to decipher what is going on in your gif.

Comment: Code this https://github.com/Darcvizer/q_p/blob/master/utilities.py

Comment: I'm need get polygons after rayCast even if it is created by a modifier